# AngularJS - How to access an array of objects within an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, nested

In c#, I'm making an array with an array of objects inside it and passing it to Angular.

Angular receives it with:

```
$scope.accounts = data.items;
```

In my cshtml, I can access these values fine:

```
<td>{{account.name}}</td>
<td>{{account.primaryAccountManager}}</td>
<td>{{account.secondaryAccountManager}}</td>
```

But not:

```
 <td>{{account.subscriptions.expirationDate}}</td>
```

What do I need to do to get the expirationDate that is within the nested array?

Comment: Maybe <td>{{account.subscriptions[i].expirationDate}}</td>?

Comment: Could you show us your data.items array

Comment: @luk492 where do you get that [i] from ...?

Comment: how is the accounts array structured?

Comment: If you want proper help provide sample data and expected results

Comment: @Martijn Welker if he's in a ng-repeat, which I think he is, instead of "i" he can use a "$index". I just wanted to give him an idea

Comment: @luk492 Why not just say $index then and give him a link ng-repeat variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a ng-repeat, use:

```
<td>{{account.subscriptions[$index].expirationDate}}</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `[ng-repeat]` directive to loop on an array.

Try that

```
<div ng-repeat="subscription in account.subscriptions">
  {{subscription.expirationDate}}
</div>
```

And don't forget to check angular docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat